# Used an incorrect SWIFT code for transfer. Will money return or still go through?

Tags: bank-account, money-transfer, mistakes, swift, italy

I made an international transfer from my bank in Italy to the U.S. The recipient account number and routing number were correct including the address, but I mistakenly used the SWIFT code of the U.S. Century Bank instead of Italian Century Bank.

It has been 3 days now but the money has not arrived at the recipient bank. I contacted my bank but all they said was money has gone. What can I do?

Comment: I would try to call the bank the swift code belongs to and ask them to investigate

Comment: it's been 7 months. Can you answer your own question now?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sent wrong payment to right IBAN but wrong SWIFT. What will happen now?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/83892/sent-wrong-payment-to-right-iban-but-wrong-swift-what-will-happen-now)

Answer (score 1):

The bank are able to trace it and arrange a refund, you need to chase them on this.  If it's a larger amount of money I would ask the bank ombudsman for help, if it is a small amount, you are better going in person and asking to speak to a manager.